# How to refer to third level lists in css?

Tags: css, list, drop-down-menu

I've currently implemented this plugin:
http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

I'd like to implement styling to third level lists and this only goes up to second level.

Issue is I'm a bit of a CSS newbie when it comes to this kind of thing and really am confused as to how I can refer to the third level & style it to also act like the second level does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: There is a link to the jsfiddle in the comments beneath this post. I'm wondering how I can do it so that the blue third level only display when the second level is hovered over?

EDIT: Fixed the issue.

Comment: create a fiddle demo what you tried sofar? instead of giving link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cs3nx55f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* third level */

#nav li ul li ul {}
```

Comment: Do you mind giving me a push in the right direction for the rest of them too? I'm trying to refer to them but it isn't being picked up bar the one you provided.

Comment: Only just seen your comment... You came right by now?

Comment: I've fixed it, it's fine now. Thanks for your help.